# some of the components goes out of screen

Tags: android

I have developed an android app that works fine, but the problem is that when I run my application on small screen phones then some components goes out of screen. So please tell what should I do with my app so that it fits on every screen?

Should I create all of these folders (given below) and copy-paste all of my app's layout files in each of these folders? Or I need to design different layout files for each of these folders?

I am new to android, please help by giving a simple example.

**Folders:**

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml
res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png
```

**XML of MainActivity of My Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.appdeveloper.appname.MainActivity"
    android:background="#ff003b"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/appLogoImage_id"
        android:src="@drawable/applogo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="1000dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/loginPassword_id"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:hint="Enter Application Password"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appLogoImage_id"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/white_cursor" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="REGISTRATION"
        android:id="@+id/regTitle_id"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appLogoImage_id"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|text"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/regName_id"
        android:layout_below="@+id/loginPassword_id"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:hint="Your Good Name"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/white_cursor"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/regPassword_id"
        android:layout_below="@+id/regName_id"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:hint="Application Password"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/white_cursor"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/regVerifyPass_id"
        android:layout_below="@+id/regPassword_id"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:hint="Verify Password"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/white_cursor"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/regRingCode_id"
        android:hint="Ringing Codeword"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/regVerifyPass_id"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/white_cursor"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/regLocationCode_id"
        android:hint="Location Codeword"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/regRingCode_id"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/white_cursor"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/regNum1_id"
        android:hint="1st Trusted Number"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/regLocationCode_id"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/white_cursor"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:phoneNumber="false" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/regNum2_id"
        android:hint="2nd Trusted Number"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/regNum1_id"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/white_cursor"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:phoneNumber="false" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/regNum3_id"
        android:hint="3rd Trusted Number"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/regNum2_id"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/white_cursor"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:phoneNumber="false" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Register"
        android:id="@+id/regButton_id"
        android:layout_below="@+id/regNum3_id"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/appLogoImage_id"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/appLogoImage_id"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/appLogoImage_id"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/appLogoImage_id"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The answer is highly dependent on what your layout actually looks like, so you should post that here as well. Other than that I recommend reading https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html and https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: @AndrewBrooke I have already gone through these links. I am new to android and I am not able to figure out solution.
My app has a login page (containing `EditTexts` and a `Button`) on `MainActivity`, then a `ListView` in next activity and some simple `EditTexts` and `Buttons` in successive activities. Moreover I am using `Relative` layout.
Now can you please figure out solution for me?

Comment: Can you add the full XML of your layout to your original post?

Comment: @AndrewBrooke I have added the XML in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you soft code your dimensions (margin, padding, textsize) in dimen.xml file, your app will have different layout in phones having different ppi (pixel per inch).

So add all your margins specially the one having 1000dp in Dimens.xml.

Reason: Android handles all the cases (hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi, ....) on its own by going through dimens.xml file and in your case you are focusing on the preview screen in XMl layout editor that is having a fixed ppi and ignoring the cases of other screens having different ppi.

Your layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.appdeveloper.appname.MainActivity"
android:background="#ff003b"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/appLogoImage_id"
    android:src="@drawable/applogo"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_0" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_50"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/loginPassword_id"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:hint="Enter Application Password"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textColorHint="#000000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appLogoImage_id"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_50"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/white_cursor" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="REGISTRATION"
    android:id="@+id/regTitle_id"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appLogoImage_id"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_50"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|text"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/regName_id"
    android:layout_below="@+id/loginPassword_id"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:hint="Your Good Name"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textColorHint="#000000"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_0"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/white_cursor"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/regPassword_id"
    android:layout_below="@+id/regName_id"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:hint="Application Password"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textColorHint="#000000"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/white_cursor"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/regVerifyPass_id"
    android:layout_below="@+id/regPassword_id"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:hint="Verify Password"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textColorHint="#000000"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/white_cursor"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/regRingCode_id"
    android:hint="Ringing Codeword"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textColorHint="#000000"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/regVerifyPass_id"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/white_cursor"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/regLocationCode_id"
    android:hint="Location Codeword"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textColorHint="#000000"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/regRingCode_id"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/white_cursor"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/regNum1_id"
    android:hint="1st Trusted Number"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textColorHint="#000000"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/regLocationCode_id"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/white_cursor"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:phoneNumber="false" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/regNum2_id"
    android:hint="2nd Trusted Number"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textColorHint="#000000"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/regNum1_id"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/white_cursor"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:phoneNumber="false" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/regNum3_id"
    android:hint="3rd Trusted Number"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textColorHint="#000000"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/regNum2_id"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/white_cursor"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:phoneNumber="false" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Register"
    android:id="@+id/regButton_id"
    android:layout_below="@+id/regNum3_id"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_15"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/appLogoImage_id"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/appLogoImage_id"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/appLogoImage_id"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/appLogoImage_id"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Your dimens.xml in res/values

```
<resources>
<dimen name="margin_10">10dp</dimen>
<dimen name="margin_0">0dp</dimen>
<dimen name="margin_15">15dp</dimen>
<dimen name="margin_30">30dp</dimen>
<dimen name="margin_50">50dp</dimen>
<dimen name="margin_20">20dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

Comment: it is not `1000dp`, consider it `0dp`

Comment: Check now i have posted both the files for you